# Prevent tikz tree nodes from overlapping

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-node

I'm drawing tree structures of sentences with tikz, where nodes contain words, which may be longer sometimes. If that occurs, they are likely to overlap with neighbouring nodes. How can I tell tikz to keep a minimum spacing between neighbouring nodes? My MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=3pt, text centered,
    font=\sffamily},
  arn_n/.style = {treenode, rectangle, text width=3em},
  arn_x/.style = {treenode},
  gray-arrow/.style = {draw=gray}
}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 10cm/#1,
  level distance = 1cm}] 
\node [arn_n]{NP}
child { node [arn_n] {N'}
    child { node [arn_n] {N'}
        child { node [arn_n] {aa}
            child { node [arn_x] {der}
            }
        }
        child { node [arn_n] {N'}
            child { node [arn_n] {AP}
                child { node [arn_x] {geduldigsten}
                }
            }
            child { node [arn_n] {N'}
                child { node [arn_n] {N}
                    child { node [arn_x] {Konservativen}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    child { node [arn_n] {N'}
        child { node [arn_n] {aa}
            child { node [arn_x] {unserer}
            }
        }
        child { node [arn_n] {N'}
            child { node [arn_n] {N}
                child { node [arn_x] {Partei}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered MWE]

In this case, the nodes containing "unserer" and "N'" overlap on the fifth level. What's a smart way to prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`forest`](http://ctan.org/pkgs/forest) does it for you:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=3pt, 
        text centered, font=\sffamily},
  arn_n/.style = {treenode, rectangle, text width=3em},
  arn_x/.style = {treenode},
  gray-arrow/.style = {draw=gray},
  edge=-{Stealth}}
[NP, arn_n
    [N', arn_n
        [N', arn_n
            [aa, arn_n
                [der, arn_x]]
            [N', arn_n
                [AP, arn_n
                    [geduldigsten, arn_x]]
                [N', arn_n
                    [N, arn_n
                        [Konservativen, arn_x]]]]]
        [N', arn_n
            [aa, arn_n
                [unserer, arn_x]]
            [N', arn_n
                [N, arn_n
                    [Partei, arn_x]]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @LukeLR I'd recommend loading the `linguistics` library, probably.

Comment: You are redefining the styles for every node in the tree. It would be better to define these once rather than repeatedly. And 2 of them are never used. There's no reason not to leave them in the `\tikzset{}` in the preamble of the document if they are globally useful.